# SQL - Insert an ID column in a certain order & return matched values

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-order-by, alter-table

I am hoping to alter a table from

[image]

Sorting the table by two columns, and adding a sequential ID column, one starting from 0, the other from 1

[image]

With the aim of being able to match the ID0 and ID1 columns, providing another column comparing the previous rows value, basically shifting a column off by one. In this example matching ID1 to ID0 and putting the corresponding ID0 value in the new column.

[image]

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, CurrPosStartDate ASC)
FROM WF_Data_Temp
```

This almost does what I want, but its not an actual new column.

```
ALTER TABLE WF_Data_Temp ADD ID_0 INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

This creates the new column as I need, but I am not sure how to specify an ORDER BY for an ALTER

Thanks

Comment: The sample data doesn't match from one picture to another. And the column names are also different here and there.

Comment: Appologies my samples are not clear, the first is meant to represent the unsorted data, the second is following a sort + inserting the two ID columns, the third is following a match of the two ID columns returning a corresponding offset column (in this case 'ID1' matches 'ID0' by shifting down 1) returning the corresponding value from 'X' to a new column 'Match'

Comment: Sorting columns separately is counter to relational concepts. [Why do you want to do this](https://xyproblem.info/)? Are the resulting sorted values for each row really supposed to be the same? Are the values unique within each column?